# WPF Webbrowser with javascript use variable defined in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am trying to pass an array defined in my wpf project in a javascript function inside an html page loaded in a Webbrowser control and i don't find any way to do that.

Example of i want to do :

Xaml:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="WBTimeGraph" />
```

c#:

```
namespace GraphNameSpace
{
    public partial class TimeGraph : Window
    {
        // MEMBERS
        public []int MyArrayOfData = new int[50];
        // METHODS
        public TimeGraph ()
        {
             InitializeComponent();

              string Dir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
              Uri tNav = new Uri(Dir + string.Format("/TimeGraph.html"));
              WBTimeGraph.Navigate(tNav);
        }
    }
}
```

HTML :

```
     <script>
        $(function () {
          // Do a Graph with MyArrayOfData
        });
     </script>
```

Comment: You can't invoke a method that *returns* the aforementioned values?

Comment: I don't want to invoke a  method, i just need to use the "ValueThaWillBeUsesByTheJavascriptFunction" in the javascript function

Comment: You could pass the data in the query string when specifying TimeGraph.html, if it's not too large. Otherwise I would create a copy of the HTML file, inject the data, and then open it.

Comment: Thanks dan, Good idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution i found is to invoke a javascript function with paramaters to update my graph and pass a serialised array as parameter

HTML :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateGraph(json) {

        var data = JSON.parse(json);
        //  Update My Graph with new data
        // This allow me to use data like the serialised array - data[0] ...

     }
 </script>
```

C# :

Added System.Web.Extension in référence to do script sérialisation

```
 private void UpdateValueInJavascriptGraph()
 {
     var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
     var json = serializer.Serialize(MyArrayOfData);  
     object result = this.WBTimeGraph.InvokeScript("UpdateGraph", new object[] { json });
 }
```